# JSON Exception:type.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, sql

This is my java code, and I have a problem in my try-catch, when I take the where user_id = ". $_SESSION['user_id'] from the query it works. I also have a classe where I save the user_id session

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Costs");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("Costs");
                String outPut = number + "€";
                employeeList.add(createEmployee("custos", outPut));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), employeeList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "Costs" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


    }
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="Parking";
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from Costs where user_id = ". $_SESSION['user_id']; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['Costs'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: So what happens when you have the WHERE in your query? Error message? Empty response? Have you checked that the `$_SESSION['user_id']` actually contains anything?

Comment: Depends... it will force you to rewrite your DB-code, which actually might change things. Like using Prepared Statements instead of concatenating your query.

Comment: It will catch the Exception and says that JSON Exception:type.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. I save the user_ID here 

if(isset($check)){
   
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $check['user_id'];
   echo "user_id";

Comment: Where do you do that? I don't see it in the code you're having issues with. Log your `$sql` variable after you have built it and check if it looks correct or not.

Comment: I did that in a diferrent php file will post the code here. Sorry if its confusing. <?php       $sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

        require_once('connection.php');

        $sql = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        $check = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_BOTH);

        //if we got some result 
        if(isset($check)){

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $check['user_id'];
            echo "user_id";

Comment: Now I'm more confused, is it the code in your question or in the comment you're having issues with? Either way, log the concatenated query (the actual string) that doesn't work and check it. Also make sure you have error reporting on and check your error log for errors.

Comment: I have problems because I save the user id, pass it to other page using SESSION, and I  concatenate with that userID from the SESSION and i get "String cannot be converted to String". I will do that thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885110/json-exception-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-appears here is the full program in order to give you context. If you please help me :/